# How can a struct be unsized?

Tags: memory, struct, rust

My mental model of data layout in Rust was that all structs' sizes have to be known at compile-time, which means all of their properties have to be known at compile-time recursively. This is why you can't have a struct member that's simply a trait (and why enums have to be used in place of union types): the size can't be known, so instead you have to use either

1. A generic, so the trait gets "reified" to a size-known struct at usage time
2. An enum, which has a finite set of possible size-known layouts
3. A `Box`, whose size is known because it's just a pointer

But in the docs for [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html), it says:

> This is an unsized type, meaning that it must always be used behind a pointer like `&` or `Box`. For an owned version of this type, see `PathBuf`.

Yet `Path` is neither a trait nor a generic struct, it's just a plain struct.

What's wrong with my mental model that this can be possible?

I found [this explanation of what dynamically-sized types *are*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait), but I still don't understand, how I would make one of my own. Is doing so a special privilege reserved for the language itself?

Comment: _"You can declare a struct (or enum or tuple) [...], containing an unsized type. A type containing an unsized type will be unsized too."_

Comment: In addition to what @E_net4isnotamoderator said: `Path` contains a `OsStr` which is a slice of memory (without a defined length). So as the content is unsized, the `Path` struct is unsized as well.

Comment: @E_net4isnotamoderator sort of. I'm still fuzzy on what these types actually look like in memory, and why they deserve their own special status instead of just being traits.

Comment: They are different things: traits only define behaviour, whereas dynamically sized types (DSTs) exist as concrete values, in a way which can only be manipulated behind a pointer because their size is not constrained. The relation between the two is that trait types (`dyn Trait`) are always DSTs, the opposite isn't true. Building your own unsized struct and making it useful is a complicated subject with many requirements and few benefits.

Comment: You can also create a struct `struc Foo {bar:str}` or (`bar:[u8]`) which is unsized. I would expect that rust optimizes it to contain just the contents of `bar`. And since it is unsized, you cannot assign it to a local (stack) variable. On the heap variable sizes are manageable (as with strings and slices).

Answer (score 3):

A struct is allowed to contain a single unsized field, and this makes the struct itself unsized. Constructing a value of an unsized type can be very difficult, and can usually only be done by using unsafe to cast a reference to a sized variant to the unsized variant.

For example, one might use [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent) to make it possible to cast an `&[u8]` to a `&MySlice` like this. This attribute makes the type guaranteed to be represented in the same way as its single field.

```
#[repr(transparent)]
struct MySlice {
    inner: [u8],
}
```

It would then be sound to convert slices like this:

```
impl MySlice {
    pub fn new(slice: &[u8]) -> &MySlice {
        // SAFETY: This is ok because MySlice is #[repr(transparent)]
        unsafe {
            &*(slice as *const [u8] as *const MySlice)
        }
    }
}
```

You could e.g. refuse to perform the conversion if the slice was not valid ascii, and now you would have a byte array that was guaranteed to point to valid ascii, just like how `&str` is an `&[u8]` that is guaranteed to be valid utf-8.